# Prove that this set of function is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

a) Given are $x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n$ and the following set of functions :

$M$ = {${f \in C[x_0,x_n]: f|_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}  \in P_2[x_{i-1},x_i], i=1,...n}$}

These functions are continuous on $[x_0,x_n]$ and on each interval 
$[x_{i-1},x_i]$ a polynomial of degree < 2. Prove that M is a vector space.

b) Now consider the functions $f_0,...f_n \in M $ with

$$
f_i(x_j) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \quad i=j \\
            0 & \quad i \neq j
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ for $i, j \in {0,...,n}$

Prove that  $f_0,...f_n$ are linear independent.

---

For a) :

0 is of degree < 2 , so $0 \in M$

Sum of two polynomials of degree < 2 is always of degree < 2.
Multiplying by a given scalar won't change the degree too.

For b) : I guess I somehow have to prove that to equal 0, all coefficients have to be 0 ? But how ?

---

Are the proofs in part a) correct ? And how do I proceed for part b) ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Assuming you already know that the set of **all** functions is a vector space (with the standard function addition and multiplication by a constant) then, yes, it is sufficient to show that this set is closed under addition and multiplication by a constant.  For (b), no it is not necessary that they be linear.  For (b), yes. look at $a_0f_0(x)+ a_1f_1(x)+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ a_nf_n(x)= 0$.  Now, see what happens if $x= x_i$ for each i in succession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(b)$ Suppose that you have 
$$
c_0f_0+\cdots+c_nf_n=0
$$
For some scalars $c_0,\dots c_n$.

Then $c_0f_0(x_0)+\cdots+c_nf_n(x_0)=c_0f_0(x_0)=c_0=0$.

In the same way you prove that $c_1=\cdots c_n=0$

Comment: But does $x$  have to be the same for each function ? Isn't it possible to have for example  $c_0f_0(x_0) + c_1f_1(x_1)+... + c_nf_n(x_n) $ or $c_0f_0(x_0) + c_1f_1(x_0)+c_2f_2(x_2)+... + c_nf_n(x_n) $ ?

Comment: You can evaluate the functions in any value that you want. But in your case, you obtain $c_0+\cdots+ c_n=0$ and this  not means neccessary  that each scalar must be zero. I evaluate in $x_0$ because it guarantees me that $c_0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

For b) If $$f= c_0f_0+c_1f_1+...+c_nf_n= 0$$ where $0$ is the $0$ of $M$, then we have $f(x_i)=0$. Since $f(x_i)=c_i$, we have $c_i = 0$,  for each $0\le x\le n$.
Thus $f_i$ s are independent.